# Why is Configuration message appearing on jpeg images exported from DICOM file?

Tags: image, dicom, clearcanvas

I am trying to make a web based dicom image viewer. I am using c# and asp.net. I am using Clear Canvas libraries found on www.clearcanvas.ca. The problem here is that when I try to export the jpeg images from dicom files the following message appears on them:

"The current configuration system does not support user-scoped setting"

On other forums I have found that this error can be removed by the application scope settings. I have tried that and still the message appears on the images. I have even shifted the user settings in app.config file to applicationsettings sections. Since web based solutions do not support user settings because the website has to run on the server. If some one has done this and removed this message from the images, then please share it here. I would really appreciate some help on removing this error. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The ClearCanvas ImageViewer components were written to using several User settings.  IIS based applications do not support user settings.  An exception is occurring within the assembly due to the lack of support for user settings and placing it on the image.

There's a couple of solutions.  You could go and modify the code by changing all of the settings to be application settings instead of user settings.  You could also create a new .NET settings provider that supports user settings that could be used within IIS.